# why i am getting mysql error in this query

Tags: mysql

I am getting mysql error after executing below query

```
select s1.Student_Id,
       s1.Total_Paid_Orders
from ((SELECT s.Student_Id,
              COUNT(o.Order_Id) as Total_Paid_Orders 
       FROM `orders` o 
       inner join students s on s.Student_Id=o.Student_Id
       WHERE o.Entry_Date<'2019-09-01 00:00:00'
       group by s.Student_Id
      ) s1
      left join (SELECT s23.Student_Id 
                 FROM `orders` o23 
                 inner join students s23 on s23.Student_Id=o23.Student_Id
                 WHERE o23.Entry_Date>='2019-09-01 00:00:00' 
                 group by s23.Student_Id 
                ) s2 on s1.Student_Id=s2.Student_Id 
      where s1.Student_Id is null
);
```

Mysql Error:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where s1.Student_Id is null) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: When you format your code properly it becomes obvious the `where` clause belongs after the final `)`

Comment: Code looks clumsy - what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: i want to get records which is not available in s2 table

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the extranneous parenthesis. Try below query -

```
SELECT s1.Student_Id,
  s1.Total_Paid_Orders
FROM
  (SELECT s.Student_Id,
    COUNT(o.Order_Id) AS Total_Paid_Orders
  FROM `orders` o
  INNER JOIN students s
  ON s.Student_Id   =o.Student_Id
  WHERE o.Entry_Date<'2019-09-01 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY s.Student_Id
  ) s1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT s23.Student_Id
  FROM `orders` o23
  INNER JOIN students s23
  ON s23.Student_Id    =o23.Student_Id
  WHERE o23.Entry_Date>='2019-09-01 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY s23.Student_Id
  ) s2 ON s1.Student_Id=s2.Student_Id
WHERE s1.Student_Id   IS NULL;
```

Comment: but by using this query it's giving me wrong records